# What type of correlation analysis should I run?

Tags: correlation, binary-data, categorical-data

Here is what I have:

- 1 nominal categorical dependent variable
- 6 nominal categorical independent variable
- 1 continuous independent variable

I used binomial regression for analysis, but my adviser insists that I use correlation instead. So I need help with the correct correlation to use.